# Can not start phpmyadmin after updating mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I updated PHPMyAdmin, then saw some errors about different versions of MySQL libraries and server. So I uninstalled and reinstalled MySQL using YUM.

Now MySQL works and I can see the MySQL database server listed in webmin modules and it has the users and databases in there, but when I go to `PHPMyAdmin` an error occurs.

var/logs/httpd/error_log shows:

```
[Tue Oct 13 09:29:33 2015] [error] [client 193.109.196.106] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'SqlParser\\Lexer' not found in /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/libraries/Util.class.php on line 634, referer: http://198.154.62.131/phpMyAdmin/
```

I tried searching for this error in Google but I found nothing.

Comment: add the `Util.class.php` 634-645 lines as well

Comment: my version of mysql is 
mysql  Ver 14.12 Distrib 5.0.95, for redhat-linux-gnu (i386) using readline 5.1  could this be the issue, as i have latest version of phpmyadmin it may not be compatible?  As I just downgraded phpmyadmin and the error changed to "#1115 - Unknown character set: 'utf8mb4' "

Comment: Edit our answer with `Util.class.php` this code

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused by mysql server version being way too old for the latest phpmyadmin.

I managed to update mysql using this method and now the phpmyadmin works again:
http://kwatog.com/blog/how-to-upgrade-mysql-5-0-to-5-5-in-centos/

But still the error is shown on phpmyadmin dashboard:
"Your PHP MySQL library version 5.0.67 differs from your MySQL server version 5.5.28. This may cause unpredictable behavior. "